# u said still it will run something in background

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char *command;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Wrong number of arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((command = malloc (strlen (argv[1]) + 6)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy (command, "echo ");
    strcat(command,argv[1]);
    system(command);
    free (command);
    return 0;
}
```

how to patch this code so there wont be any privelige given to user
the thing is by running this i can get acess as root user how to edit this so that this will not happen

Comment: i am not running the code in root

Comment: It's allowed to use punctuation marks in questions.

Comment: So who is running the code?  If it's the user running the thing, then they won't be able to do anything they aren't able to do at a terminal.  Could you clarify the description a bit?

Comment: Your question title makes no sense. Also please try to use punctuation and proper spelling in your questions, otherwise it is hard to understand and people will simply move on rather than try to decipher it.

Comment: Could you give a more representative title in regard of your question?

Comment: FYI- this is a follow-up to Krishnan's earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419139/linux-how-to-patch-this-code/5422419#5422419

Comment: So the person referred to by "u said" would be pax or yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Call [`seteuid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/seteuid) to drop root privileges before calling `system(3)`.

Comment: i didnot get u explain me a bit

Comment: @krishnan When someone mentions a function and gives a number in parentheses, it means that you can find out about it by looking in the appropriate section of the man pages.  In other words, instead of asking someone else to explain it to you, try 'man 2 seteuid' and read a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `system()`?  The easiest way to avoid security problems is to not feed user input into `system()`.  In your example, what is your `system()` call doing that you can't do with a simple `printf`?

The program is limited to the permissions of the user account that runs the program.  Run the program using a limited-access user account that doesn't have privileges to use `sudo`, `su`, etc.  Create a "jail" using [chroot](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/chroot-practices.html) and run the program inside that jail as a non-privileged user to limit the amount of your system that the program has access to.